# How to call CLI from a controller on ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Our system is written in ZF2. I'm trying to call a `ZFTool` console command programmatically, if there's a way to do that. All documentation I have found so far points to call a Controller action from CLI, instead of CLI programmatically from a controller.

If there's no default way to do this, a workaround would be fine as long as it's testable. Thanks in advance.

**PS:** I'm new to ZF2, I come from `Laravel` where you have a facade class to execute commands from a controller class `Artisan::call('my:command')`.

Comment: Is it definitely a ZFTool command you want to call and not just using custom console commands created with the console lib?

Comment: If you check the repo it's just like any other module: https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool/tree/master/src/ZFTool and is just bootsrapped zia zp.php. if you give an exmaple what you're trying to do maybe I can make a suggestion

Comment: @Andrew suppose you wanna call `controller create` from a controller (kind of a ZFTool wrapper).

Comment: depends how you are going to use it, it's just a regular controller you can either route to, or instantiate and use - depending on how you need to do things

Comment: @Andrew I'm literally going to run `php vendor/bin/zf.php controller create MyController MyModule` inside a controller class programatically. Could you provide an example?

Comment: simplest way would be to use exec() but that's pretty horrible. You could route to the controller but i'll need to write/test something before I post for that